# Displaying a modal with table display value for one entry in a .each loop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have followed and successfully implemented the solution to a similar query here: [Displaying a modal for one entry in a .each loop - Rails / Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737201/displaying-a-modal-for-one-entry-in-a-each-loop-rails-bootstrap).

However, by default a `display` property of `block` is applied to modal

[image].

I think this is via bootstrap and `aria-hidden`. Is there a way that I can override this and apply a value of `table` via bootstrap or will I have to use some Javascript solution when the modal is displayed when `aria-hidden` is set to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the style is added by JS from bootstrap. On the other hand, this should work:

```
.your_element_class[aria-hidden="false"] {
  display: table !important;
}
```